# Problem with Mobile navigation menu with wp_nav_menu() function in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Here is the problem. I'm creating a theme in WordPress and I have trouble with dynamic navigation menu on Mobile devices.

Here is the code which I use:

```
<nav id="primary-menu" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button> 

                    <a class="logo" href="#page"> 
                        <img class="logo-dark" src="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/assets/images/logo/logo-dark.png" alt="appy Logo">
                        <img class="logo-light" src="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/assets/images/logo/logo-light.png" alt="appy Logo">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <?php 
                    wp_nav_menu (array (
                        'theme_location' => 'menu-1', 
                        'container' => 'nav',
                        'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse pull-right',
                        'menu_id' => 'navbar-collapse-1',
                        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav nav-pos-right navbar-left nav-split',
                    ));
                ?>

                <!--<div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="navbar-collapse-1">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pos-right navbar-left nav-split">
                        <li class="active"><a data-scroll="scrollTo" href="#slider">home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a data-scroll="scrollTo" href="#feature2">feature</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a data-scroll="scrollTo" href="#banner">author</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a data-scroll="scrollTo" href="#reviews">reviews</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a data-scroll="scrollTo" href="#pricing">pricing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a data-scroll="scrollTo" href="#cta">download</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div> -->
                <!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Menu in functions.php file:

```
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'bookfolio' )
    ) );
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'bookfolio_setup' );
```

I put the HTML code in the comment so you can see how it looks like.

The desktop version works perfectly, but the problem is on Mobile devices.

Comment: and whats your problem?

Comment: Mobile menu doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use custom walker to display menu in bootstrap CSS
https://github.com/dupkey/bs4navwalker

Comment: Found a solution in this one on [Github](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker)